# How to show linked entity inside another entity

Tags: usability, web-app, layout, interface, information-architecture

I need to show some way to indicate that the green colour entity is linked and not owned by the parent (blue) entity you were currently in. [image]

Currently i'm using colour variation like here and wrapped those inside a box with title.

It seems too cluttered when it comes with lot of data and tables. Is there any nice way to show this.  Any application samples/suggestions/UI links would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to show that the green element is clickable, while the blue element is clickable (differently)? Also assuming the sidebar acts independently.

Comment: No need to have clickable functionality. Green element has it's own data (like tables) that linked form another data set.  My concern is adding this kind of box separation seems to be too clattered. 

Sidebar is independent and it's having navigation links to different tabs.
~Thanks~

Comment: Okay, I was thinking too literally about 'linked' in terms of websites. In this case I would make the 'green' area a shade of the same main blue, meanwhile make the sidebar differentiated from the content.

Staying in the shade of the main content helps associate the child content, while letting you set new content apart through different styles.

In this case you might want to make the sidebar stand out more (ie the green that got left behind.)

Comment: Thank you very much.  Yes. adding shade would be of primary colour would be nice too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I'm thinking is using the link icon along with a title: **Linked to XYZ**, and when user clicks/hovers on it; show more details of the linking in a popup, callout, or new page.

[image]

Comment: yes. this is a nice idea too. I will consider this as well. thanks